# How to open new tab in existing window using keyboard shortcuts on Ubuntu

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, tabs

Keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> opens a new terminal window on Linux. By default it opens 1 new terminal window.

Is there a way how to customize how many new tabs are going to be opened? E.g. by using this shortcut it will open 2 tabs by default.

What is the right keyboard shortcut to open a new tab in existing terminal ?

I want to have 2 tabs opened and switch between them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to open gnome-terminal with more than one tab when you open it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut, go to **System Settings** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** → **Custom Shortcuts** and add a new <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut as follow:

[image: custom shortcut]

Select **Reassign** when you are asked:

[image]

Now, to open a new tab in gnome-terminal, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. To access/view/edit your terminal shortcuts go to **Edit** → **Keyboard Shortcuts...**:

[image: terminal Keyboard Shortcuts]

Comment: what kind of ubuntu are you using? I am using 12.10...trying to follow your steps, but stacked at **select reasign**.When I create a custom shortcut according to screen 1, it does not asks me for keyboard shortcuts ( e.g. CTRL+Alt+T), instead it is disabled..

Comment: @maro Just click with your muouse where is written `Ctrl+Alt+T` (where you say that is written `Disabled`) in [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tvFB5.png). Afer click it will say `New accelerator...` - now type your shortcut (this keys: `Ctrl+Alt+T`).

Answer (score 40):

Looking in the menu I can see that the shortcut to open a new tab is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 18):

Once you have Terminal open you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and that will open another tab.  see image below.  Once you do that you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> to switch.

[image]